# Git Plugin in Jenkins doesn't get environment variable

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

There are two jobs: parent job and child job.

There is an environment variable for branch name which is configured in parent job in batch script: `setx BRANCH_NAME development`. I tried configuring git Branch Specifier with it in child job (`${BRANCH_NAME}`), but I get an error in console

```
git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/${BRANCH_NAME}^{commit} # timeout=10
git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/${BRANCH_NAME}^{commit} # timeout=10
git rev-parse origin/${BRANCH_NAME}^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build.
```

I am 100% certain git is fine, branch exists.

Comment: Not a full answer, but I recently configured a Jenkins instance and I recall reading that your environment variables can be overwritten by precedence rules.  So something may be providing a different value for `BRANCH_NAME`.

Comment: We can see that jenkins cann't recognize environment variable ${BRANCH_NAME}. If environment variable has been overwritten then error code must be like '....refs/remotes/origin/<another value of variable>.....'

Comment: In your log snippet, `${BRANCH_NAME }` has a space between the variable name and the ending curly-brace. If that's not just a typo in the question, try removing it